# How to ignore errors in Azure API Management policy execution

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have `<log-to-eventhub`> policy at global level in API Management instance. The policy used to store the incoming request metadata in eventhub. This policy just serves the logging. Recently my eventhub was down and all API requests ended with 500 Error .

How to ensure that the request will be served irrespective of eventhub logging. that means, my policy expression evaluation should be ignored if there is an error in `<log-to-eventhub>`.

Note- `<on-error>` policy section can not be implemented.

Comment: If there is no `on-error` section, callers will receive 400 or 500 HTTP response messages if an error condition occurs.

Comment: `<on-error>` policy section cannot be implemented means do you want the steps to implement that?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Yes, callers will receive 500 error on policy failure. I am looking for how to handle exceptions in policy expressions without use of <on-error>. <on-error> section is already used in my global policy and can not be used in this case due to design limitations.